# Две задачи на Паскале

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте, прошу помощи по двум задачкам на Паскале.

1) Напишите программы вычисления сумм для n слагаемых вида (і+1), і=1, 2,...,n

2) Напишите программы вычисления произведений 2 * 4 * 6 * ... * (2n);

1) Делал вот таким образом

```
program 123;
VAR i: integer; s:real;
readln (n);
BEGIN
s:=0;
for i := 1 to n do s := s + (i+1);
writeln('S=',s);
END;
```

Где к s прибавляется сумма предыдущих.

Потом подсказали вариант:

```
program wtf;
var i,s,n,x:integer;
begin
writeln('vvedite n');
readln(n);
for i:=1 to n do
begin
writeln(i,'slagaenoe=',x+i);
s:=s+x+i;
end;
writeln('sum=',s);
end;
```

Правильный ли он?

2)

```
program proizv;
var i,p,n:integer;
begin
i:=2;s:=1;
write('vvedite n ');
readln(n);
while i<=2*n do
begin
p:=p*i;
inc(i,2);
end;
writeln(p);
end;
```

Comment: @intranet, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: 1) вариант №1 не откомпилируется. вариант №2 может быть правильным, в зависимости от того, как понимать условие задачи. я бы написал как в варианте 1, а лучше просто свернул бы сумму арифметической прогрессии и не гонял бы циклы.

Comment: 2) снова не откомпилируется, вы перепутали s и p. идея правильная, хотя я бы использовал цикл for

Comment: Учебные задачи надо решать самостоятельно, иначе никакого толку не будет.

Comment: Обе задачи по сути на понимание прогресий, 1 арифметическая, 2 геометрическая, учите математику а то Ваши программы будут так же тормозить, как Windows (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так, наверное:

```
Program Zadacha1;

Uses CRT;

Var
   i, n, Sum: Integer;

Begin
  ClrScr;
  Write('N = ');
  ReadLn(N);

  Sum:=0;
  For i:=1 To N Do
      Begin
        WriteLn('Element summi raven: ', i+1); // вывод текущего слагаемого
        Sum := Sum + (i + 1); // вычисление суммы
      End;

  WriteLn('Summa ravna: ', Sum);

  WriteLn;

  WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!');
  ReadLn;
End.

Program Zadacha2;

Uses CRT;

Var
   p: LongInt;
   i, j, n: Byte;

Begin
  ClrScr;
  Write('N = ');
  ReadLn(N);

  p:=1; // произведение начинается с единички!
  j:=2; // первый элемент произведения
  For i:=1 To N Do
    Begin
      WriteLn('Mnojitel raven: ', j);
      p:=p*j;
      Inc(j, 2);
      WriteLn('Proizvedeine ravno: ', p);
    End;

  WriteLn;

  WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!');
  ReadLn;
End.
```

Если Вы внимательно сравните свой код первой задачи с моим, то немного отличий найдёте, - а, вот, код второй задачи отличается. Во второй задаче мне непонятно: во-первых -   условие на цикле (i<=2*n), во-вторых - произведение (переменная p) у Вас не инициализирована, поэтому будет ошибка (Паскаль инициализирует переменные нулями, если бы был язык Си, то в переменной было бы что-то не понятно что - "мусор") и в-третьих у Вас этот код не откомпилируется, т. к. у Вас переменная s не объявлена (про это Вам уже сказали в комментарии). И еще добрый совет: форматируйте код даже небольшой - так намного легче в нём разобраться и найти ошибку.

З. Ы. Во второй задаче можно сократить количество проходов цикла, если произведение сразу начать с первого элемента, тогда код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
  p:=2;
  j:=2;
  WriteLn('Mnojitel raven: ', j);
  WriteLn('Proizvedeine ravno: ', p);
  For i:=2 To N Do
    Begin
      p:=p*j;
      Inc(j, 2);
      WriteLn('Mnojitel raven: ', j);
      WriteLn('Proizvedeine ravno: ', p);
    End;
```

Answer (score 2):

Первую задачу можно решить по формуле, как предлагал [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd).

В общем виде формула: `s = ( a1 + aN ) * N / 2`. 
В данной задаче a1 всегда равно 2, а `aN == N + 1`, следовательно: `s = ( 3 + N ) * N / 2`